# Call CodeBehind Method from JavaScript with parameter

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to call a code behind method from JavaScript code.
This works fine, but I am not sure how can I pass a JavaScript parameter to the method. If I put any value between the parenthesis, it is related as a CodeBehind context rather then script context. What is the solution to pass this parameter?

JavaScript:

```
var arg = this.id
<% setSelection(arg); %>
```

C#:

```
[WebMethod]
public void setSelection(string productID)
{
   Session["selection"] = productID
}
```

I get this error of course:
CS0103: The name 'arg' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `setSelection(arg)` call is not calling the code behind from JavaScript. It is getting called on the server side, before the HTML response is even output to the browser, way before the JavaScript executes. Also the `arg` is treated as a C# variable.

If you want to make the call from JavaScript, you need to use AJAX. See [this example](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using%5fPage%5fMethods%5fin%5fASPNET%5fAJAX.aspx).